# Header Issues with Crystal to SSRS Conversion

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, header, report

We are in the process of converting our Crystal Reports to SSRS.   We have come across a report in Crystal that has 4 page headers.  However, the page headers are only displayed on certain conditions.   So we made use of the visibility property based on the conditions passed to it.   That works.   The problem is because there are various fields, either visible or not, the header is statically one size.  This creates a lot of white space when printing the actual report.   I have also tried creating a tablix in the body and conditionally displaying rows, however, one of the conditions we check is page number which cannot be used in the body of an ssrs report.   So I'm leaning towards putting the header info back in the header but I am not sure how to eliminate the white space.

Let me know what you think my best course of action is.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you add a few screenshots? i'm struggling to understand why the fields can't be "on top of each other"

Comment: I did try that and it left me with not as much white space.

Comment: I did try that and it left me with not as much white space.   So say my header has 15 lines.  They each contain their own unique data.  On page one, I want to show lines 1-9.   On page 2, I want show line 3, 10-15.   For both pages I have set the visibility to match the scenarios.   But even when I move lines 10-15 stacked under lines 4.   I get 4 rows of white space on page 2 because the header boundary is static and right up against the bottom of the 9th line, even though the fields visibility is off.   The header appears to not be able to shrink.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a text box in the header then right click, expression:

```
=IIF(Globals!PageNumber = 1,"Some text" & chr(10) & chr(13),"")
&IIF(Globals!PageNumber = 2,"Some text" & chr(10) & chr(13),"")
&IIF(Globals!PageNumber = 2,"Some text" & chr(10) & chr(13),"")
&IIF(Globals!PageNumber = 3,"Some text" & chr(10) & chr(13),"")
&IIF(Globals!PageNumber = 4,"Some text" & chr(10) & chr(13),"")
```

Comment: I had kind of figured it would come to that.   I was just making sure I wasn't overlooking anything.

Comment: After trying the above out.  I still get whitespace.  No matter what the visibility or content of the textboxes.   It is like header will not shrink.   I found this nifty consomewhitespace property.  But mine was already set to true.

Comment: how big did you make the textbox? i would just have made it one line high then allow it to expand

Comment: The data I need to display in the header is in table format.  Not in a tablix though obviously.